# Does Include load all related entities or the specified ones?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship, navigation-properties

When going through a learning [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) about related entity loading in Entity Framework MSDN, I came across the following:

> It is also possible to eagerly load **multiple levels of related
>   entities**. The queries below show examples of how to do this for both
>   collection and reference navigation properties.
>
> ...[Examples demonstrating the above]...
>
> Note that **it is not currently possible to filter which related
>   entities are loaded**. Include will always being in all related
>   entities.

This seems slightly confusing, because the two statements seem to be in contradiction to each other. Am I missing something here?

For example, I could specify the `Mother` navigation property should be included for every `Child` in a `Children` DBSet I am querying, like so:

```vb
Dim myQuery = From children In context.Children.Include("Mother")
              Select child
```

Does that mean the `Father` navigation property will also be eagerly evaluated for every `Child`?

If this is not the case (`Include` only eagerly loads what you tell it to), is there a way to eagerly load *all* navigation properties without specifying them?

Comment: by **not currentrly filtering**, one means that you cannot only load mother being less tan 30 year old, you load all the mothers for the selected children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, highlighted this way it is a bit confusing. And your confusion is also caused by the fact that you happen to focus on reference navigation properties.

Looking at collections makes it clear.

> it is not currently possible to filter which related entities are loaded

which means: you can only load *all* entities in a child collection, not entities that meet some condition. **Never will other navigation property be loaded than the ones specified in the `Include`.**

The `Include` method started out as the method with the string argument that you show. Later, an extension method was added that allows specifying the navigation properties by expressions:

```
context.Children.Include(c => c.Mother)
```

especially when a collection is `Include`d:

```
context.Parents.Include(c => c.Children)
```

it seems very natural that the collection could be filtered:

```
context.Parents.Include(c => c.Children.Where(x => x.IsActive))
```

It compiles, but this is not possible (runtime exception). The reason is that the expression is only used to obtain the name of the nav property in order to call the original `Include` method (with the string argument).

I think this is the reason why this restriction is emphasized in the post you refer to.

---

> is there a way to eagerly load all navigation properties without specifying them

No, there isn't. That would be "dangerous", because having many `Includes` is a real performance killer. You better specify `Includes` carefully.

Comment: On that note you could totally write an extension method to include all nav properties (regardless of that its probably a bad idea)

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Of course. I assumed the OP was looking for an out of the box solution. IIRC there have been answers here at SO offering such extension methods. But again, I wouldn't use them. An innocent looking change in the model could have dramatic effects where they're not expected.